# Blurred UIImageView Sizing Problems

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, blur

A UIViewController I'm presenting has a UIImageView, namely `backgroundImageView`, to be the VC's background and set to fill the whole screen.

I want the UIImageView to be presented with a dark blur effect provided by iOS but the following sizing issue temporarily occurs(on device but not on the simulator) when I first present the view controller:

[image: Problematic Blur Size]

Inside `viewDidLoad()`:

```
// `locationImage` is passed during the segue
backgroundImageView.image = locationImage
backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = backgroundImageView.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
backgroundImageView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

The above view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` is set to be as `currentContext`.

If I temporarily remove the blur effect, I see that the background image I gave the view controller got properly set. However once the blur effect is applied, sizing issues occur momentarily.

What exactly is causing this?

Comment: Have you thought about using auto layout instead of setting the frame and autoresizing mask?  If you stick with this method instead of setting .frame to .bound create a CGRect with origin of 0,0 and size of the bounds.size.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Actually no. I haven't thought about using AutoLayout previously. Although I just tried it with no luck in return. Still the exact same effect. Also when you stated `bounds.size` what exactly did you meant?

Comment: Doing this: blurEffectView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height).  Could you edit the question to show the auto layout.

Comment: Yes but bounds of what exactly? I tried the bounds of the view but again with the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant backgroundImageView.bounds just explicitly setting the origin x and y to zero.  Failing that maybe the frame of the backgroundImageView itself it incorrect.

Comment: I was testing your suggestion under iOS 11 and it kinda worked: sizing issue disappeared but now I could see the blurred background's image changing instantly once the VC is presented. I wanted to see it in iOS 10, so switched devices and unfortunately still the same issue there.

Comment: Sorry I'm only just installing the beta at the moment.  Once that's done I will check it out.

Comment: If you mean that it's all positioned and sized correctly but when the view controller is shown you see the blur being applied (almost like a fade affect) then that's just the way it works unfortunately.  The background image view displays and then the blur effect is applied over the top but the background image has to be setup first.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth No need to be sorry mate. :] What you showed is pretty helpful anyways. I'll do some more testing and get back to you. Also I suspected it was iOS blur's problem of having a delay but couldn't conclude on it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the frame of blurEffectView inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` or in `viewDidLayoutSuviews()`

[here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) you can find more information  about viewcontroller's lifecycle

Comment: Sorry that I forgot this but I previously tried both of these with no luck. At first, I thought as well that it's a view life cycle issue but nothing changes. Still the same above issue.